# secure method to move form data between pages

Tags: php, sql, forms, session

I'm creating a form but I need to move data from form  fields back and forth between pages. I don't need to save the data after the page is submitted yet.

I know that I can use sessions (server side)and sql but I don't know which one is more secure or easier to implement and when I use sessions I can get the data to move forward on the pages but when I hit the back button it disappeared.

is one better than the other?
Is there a way to use sessions to move data back and forth between form fields?
page 1

```
<?php
//startssession
session_start();
//datatostore
$_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;
$test1 = $_POST["test1"] ;
$test2 = $_POST["test2"] ;
$test3 = $_POST["test3"] ;
$email = $_POST["email"] ;
?>
```

page 2

```
<?php
// starts the session.
session_start();
// data to pull and display in test text box.
$test1 = $_POST["test1"] ;
$test2 = $_POST["test2"] ;
$test3 = $_POST["test3"] ;
$email = $_POST["email"] ;
?>
```

Comment: Is the data being transmitted on the server side, or the client side?

Comment: server side. i have added to the content

Comment: Use session variables only when absolutely necessary.  This is not one of those situations.  The reason is that the user can change their values in ways you did not envision.

Answer (score 0):

Use sessions

when you hit the back button, that page probably does not have

```
session_start();
```

If you do not have that then you will not be able to access the session data.

This is fairly secure for what you are doing but I would also insure you have SSL on your site when you go to production for another layer of security.